# How to call AdViewHolder class constructor in adapter that is in fragment

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

```
public class Near_By_Places_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Near_By_Places_Adapter.ViewHolder> {


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == 1) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams attributLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            attributLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(attributLayoutParams);
            linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
            adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            linearLayout.addView(adView);
            **return new AdviewViewHolder(linearLayout);**
        } else {

            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_single_row, parent, false));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder.getItemViewType() == 1)
            return;

        if (holder.getItemViewType() == 2) {

            Picasso.get().load(list.get(position).id).fit().into(holder.IvImg);
            Picasso.get().load(list.get(position).id1).fit().into(holder.IvImg1);
            Picasso.get().load(list.get(position).id2).fit().into(holder.IvImg2);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (list.get(position).text.equals("admob") &&
                list.get(position).text1.equals("admob") &&
                list.get(position).text2.equals("admob")) {
            return 1;

        } else
            return 2;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView IvImg, IvImg1, IvImg2;



        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            IvImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tpyeicon_new);
            IvImg1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tpyeicon_new1);
            IvImg2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tpyeicon_new2);

            IvImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        } else {
                            onClickListener();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }
                }
            });
            IvImg1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        } else {
                            onClickListener();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }
                }
            });
            IvImg2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        } else {
                            onClickListener();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    class AdviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        AdviewViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


        }
    }
}
```

This line shows error

> return new AdviewViewHolder(linearLayout);

Error:

```
Near_By_Places_Adapter adapter class in fragement 
incompatible types.
Required:
com.example.engr.Fragments.Near_By_Places_Fragment.Near_By_Places_Adapter.ViewHolder
Found:
com.example.engr.Fragments.Near_By_Places_Fragment.Near_By_Places_Adapter.AdviewViewHolderstrong text
```